# GIT fatal: could not read from rempote repository

Tags: git, ubuntu, permissions

I am very new to git and ubuntu. I installed my ubuntu server today and I am now trying to set up a git repository for me and some friends who's starting a project. However, no matter what i do I keep getting the same error:

```
fatal: '/git.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: could not read from rempote repository

please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I am almost 100% certain that the path is correct, and I've tried i million different pathcombinations and nothing works. Do I need to set any special permission on ubuntu before pushing or have I missed anything else?

this is how i do it

On ubuntu server in /var/www:

```
sudo mkdir git.git
cd git.git/
git --bare init
```

On windows, from desktop via Git Bash:

```
mkdir git.git
cd git.git/
git init
```

then add some text file.

```
git . add
git commit -m "Initial Upload"
git remote add origin k2@'server-ip':/git.git
git push origin master
```

get promted to put in password and after that error occurs.

Comment: You don't necessarily _have_ to specify the remote when pushing from a local git repo (I suspect that's what you're doing).  What's your command line ?

Comment: not sure what you mean with local git repo? I've got ubuntu server installed on one computer, while trying to push from another computer to the ubuntu. I'm using git bash at the moment

Comment: It would help if you edited your post and added all the commands that eventually led to the error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would name a folder **git.git**

Let's say your project folder is project

On server:

```
$mkdir project
$cd project
$git init
$touch README.md
$git add README.md
$git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

On your desktop:

```
$git clone k2@server-ip:project.git
```

This will create a folder called project on your desktop with 'README.md' inside

Edit: The problem with what you were doing is that you were naming the folder 'git.git'.
It should only be named 'git', although that is also confusing because git itself create a folder called '.git' inside the folder 'git'. Confusing isn't it? Better give a meaningful name to your project folder that has nothing to do with git.